# How can I retrieve the values from textboxes and use them in JSP?

Tags: jsp

How can I retrieve the values from textboxes and use them in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the next jsp? (the one thats in the form action) then your answer is `${nameOfTextboxHere}`

or if you mean in the same page, you will have to use javascript. - See [w3schools javascript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)